# Put elements of an array on another decreasingly in C

Tags: c, arrays

I'm new at C I have a question regarding the arrays

I have two arrays where the elements are stored decreasingly:

```
int a[]={50, 40, 25, 8, 6};

int b[] = {38, 25, 2};
```

and I pretend to store the bigger elements of both arrays in array a, and discard the rest of them. to make something like this

```
int a[]={50, 40, 38, 25, 25}
```

I know that I have to use cycles, but i don't know what to put, something like this

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
    int a[]={50, 40, 25, 8, 6};
    int b[] = {38, 25, 2};
    int i, j, w, x;

    for(i=0; i<3; i++){

        for(j=0; j<5; j++){
            x=b[i];
            w=j;
            while(w>0 && a[j-1]<b[i]){
                 a[w]=a[w-1];
                 j--;
            }
            a[w]=x;
        }
    }


    for(i=0;i<5; i++){
        printf("[%d]", a[i]);
    }
return 0;
}
```

but dosen't work. thanks :)

Comment: Is it necessary to put the result values in `a` because it is the one being processed

Comment: @Pablo I didn't know that functions. but I have to do with cycles.

Comment: @JoshKisb not necessary. Are you saying that I have to create another variable?

Comment: Can you use `while` loops or does the homework say it must be `for` loops?  One way to think of this is swapping elements between a[] and b[] until you stop finding any bigger elements in b[] that need to be swapped with smaller elements in a[].  loop and see if there is 1 element to swap, until you do not find one.

Comment: @DaveS No, I can use while loops. I only put that because I thought was useful

Comment: @Pablo Sorry but your solution look strange don't answer in comment do a answer, you are currently confuse the OP

Comment: Yeah - can you not just keep an index for each array, compare the values indexed and and just merge them into a temp array?  If you insist, you can copy the result back into a.

Comment: @Stargateur I see that I've misread the description of the problem, I get why the OP got confused. Sorry. I've removed my previous comments because they were wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are on a mission to fill up an array of 5 then you only need 1 loop to 5

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

    int a[]={50, 40, 25, 8, 6};
    int b[] = {38, 25, 2};
    int i, val[5];
    int ai = 0, bi = 0; //current a index and b index

    for(i=0; i<5; i++){ 

        if (a[ai] > b[bi]) { 
            val[i] = a[ai]; 
            ai++;
        }
        else {
            val[i] = b[bi];
            bi++;
        }
    }

    for(i=0;i<5; i++){
        printf("[%d]", val[i]);
    }
return 0;
}
```

EDIT:

like someone mentioned, you also need to watch out for a situation where you run out of elements in one of the arrays. 
For example if all elements of b are loaded into val then the index bi will end up being `3` which is out of bounds and the check of `if (a[ai] > b[3])` may cause issue.

To solve this adding a simple check before comparison will suffice
Since this is somewhat of homework and array a is same size as resulting array, you could simply check `bi`

```
if ((bi < 3) && (a[ai] > b[bi])) {
//...
```

Comment: OP ask to change a, not a big different but, plus your code style hurt ;)

Comment: @JoshKisb thank you very much for you answer. I think I can use this :)

Comment: Watch out for the scenario in which you run out of elements in one of the arrays.